# UITableView to increase height dynamically with Scrolling Disabled?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am designing an app which has a scroll view and over it a content view having a table view with scrolling disabled . Now I want that the table view would increase its size dynamically as per my array contents. I have did some coding and I am putting my constraints screen shot so as to make things more clear -

My constraint list -

[image]

Now here is my code to populate the table view & increase its size to the content view-

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellreuse", forIndexPath: indexPath) 
        cell.textLabel?.text = name[indexPath.row]

         tableview.frame.size = tableview.contentSize



        return cell


    }
```

here is my main story board screenshot
[image]

So now when I run my code the content size is not increased as per my table view's size. So here is how it looks like on a 4s  -

[image]

So how to also adjust my content view as per the increased height of table view dynamically supporting all constraints laid out in IB?

Comment: Don't set the frame of contentView to increase it's height. Create an `IBOutlet` for the height constraint and set it's value based on the number of records your table view should display.

Comment: why? are you going to add some other subviews into the scroll view?

Comment: Table view already descends from scroll view. Nesting them sounds very dangerous.

Comment: I will suggest , just create **IBOutlet** for tableView and in **HeightForRowAtIndex** method calculate the total height based on your number of data and then set the **contentSize** of scrollview based on that .

Comment: @Gandalf How to do that? Give an example please.

Comment: @Wain No I just want that table view should dynamically increase its height as per the content and scroll view's content would resize accordingly.

Comment: so whats the purpose of the scroll view?

Comment: @Wain  I have updated my question please have a look

Comment: @Gandalf But the content size is remaining the same & its not increasing the size.

Comment: @G.Abhisek did you get the solution for the same? Please tell me if you got something. I am also trying to do same.

Comment: Ya the accepted answer is the trick but remember if you are having a dynamic height cell table view then tableView.contentsize doesn't calculate the height properly.

Comment: If then also u hv any further querie....try to send me your demo code at abhisekbunty94@gmail.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these instructions.
Constraints Required: -
**MainView to ScrollView** - leading = 0, trailing = 0, top = 0, bottom = 0;
**ScrollView to ContentView** - leading = 0, trailing = 0, top = 0, bottom = 0, contentView.width = mainView.width, contentView.height = "Some constant"
**ContentView to TableView** - leading = 8, trailing = 8, top = 518(as per your screenshot), bottom = 64;

Now you need to create an `IBOutlet` for the height constraint of `contentView`, which we have given a random constant value earlier; let's call it `contentViewHeightConstraint`.

Now once you got the records in your array you need to call `reloadData` and increase the height of `contentView` as per the number of records in your table.

`contentViewHeightConstraint.constant = 518 + 44*(name.count) + 64;`
Also remove the code that you have in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` for setting the size of tableView.

Comment: What is tje best way to calculate tableView's content size correctly when my cells are dynamic in nature. As tableView.contentSize gives varying results.

Answer (score 0):

if arrayForOfferTable.count <= 6{

```
            //offertableheight.constant = CGFloat( 400)

            offertableheight.constant = CGFloat( 46*arrayForOfferTable.count + 40)


        }
```

make your tableview height constraint outlet from storyboard and u can change the height of table view dynamically like me here 46 is the cell height and arrayForOfferTable.cont

Comment: I have put the table view height constraint as greater than equal. So its changing its height. The height of the content view is not changing thats it? You can see the screen shot.

Comment: I have didi as u said but it only resulted in the increase of my constraint size not the content view size.